# laravel use session to store input field and pass to another page

Tags: php, laravel

Im new in laravel I have form with input fields but I want to send the input values and dispaly in other page using session to check them later
***Please answer with code please***

**Form:**

```
   <form id="booking-form">
 <input class="indexinput" type="text" id="country" name="country" 
 placeholder="Country">
<input class="indexinput" type="text" id="state" name="state" 
placeholder="State">
<input class="indexinput" type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="city">
</form>

 <button class="button getbids" >GET BIDS</button> 


 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', '.getbids', function() {
  var loggedIn = {{ auth()->check() ? 'true' : 'false' }};
   if (loggedIn)
  window.location.replace('customer/dashboard');
  if(!loggedIn)
  $('#loginModal').modal('show'); 
   });
   </script>
```

**Route**

```
  Route::group(['middleware'=>['rolecustomer']], function () {

  Route::get('/customer/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('customer.dashboard');
 });
```

**controller:**

```
  public function index()
   {
   return view('index.customer.customerdashboard');
     }
```

Comment: Please describe more clearly what exactly you want to do. What do you mean with "another page". A page after submitting your form? A page that the user can visit later on his own? Why don't you want to save that in your database? Please have a [look to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#storing-data) too.

Comment: I only want to save it in session because many user will use this so session is better, and its clear I think I have form and when submit it goes to page with route customer/dashboard so in this page want to display the data from the form thats it

Answer (score 0):

You can put values in session (in the controller) like this :

```
$request->session()->put('sampleid', $samplevalue);
```

And retrieve them on blade page like this:

```
@if(Session::has('sampleid'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
             {{Session::get('sampleid')}} 
        </div>
    @endif
```

And in controller like this:

```
if($request->session()->has('sampleid')) 
{ 
 $request->session()->get('collegeid');
}
```

Comment: which controller? I have to put all of them in one controller including $request->session()->put('sampleid', $samplevalue); ? and what about $request? I have to add request to function?

Comment: This totally depends on your logic. About $request, you can put that as a function parameter or you can set session using facades.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to redirect an user if the user is not logged in on a certain request. In laravel there is middleware to take care of this. Have a look at the documentation. It's not that hard to setup.

All this authentication rules can be handled with Laravel middleware.

Documentation Middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, i understand that you are trying to check whether a user is authenticated after clicking the submit button. If he is authenticated, you are redirecting him to `customer/dashboard`. If he is not authenticated, you are displaying a login modal.

The problem is you are redirecting the user to a page using javascript and you can't get the data submitted using the form. So i guess you are trying to use `session` to get the form data in `customer/dashboard`. you can achieve what you want way simply like below.

```
<form id="booking-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('customer.dashboard') }}">
```

change your javascript code to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', '.getbids', function() {
  var loggedIn = {{ auth()->check() ? 'true' : 'false' }};
   if (loggedIn)
  $('#booking-form').submit();
  if(!loggedIn)
  $('#loginModal').modal('show'); 
   });
   </script>
```

Now make your route as

```
 Route::any('/customer/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('customer.dashboard');
```