# Laravel, Pass input variables from page to other using session

Tags: php, laravel

Please note that I'm new in Laravel, so I need serious help and since 3 days looking for solution but no luck.
All I need just to view or display the value of the input text from the form booking-form to customer/dashboard page, please note that can't send the input data untill you login and this is working fine, but how to pass data and display in the next page?
***Please answer with code please***

**Form:**

```
   <form id="booking-form">
 <input class="indexinput" type="text" id="country" name="country" 
 placeholder="Country">
<input class="indexinput" type="text" id="state" name="state" 
placeholder="State">
<input class="indexinput" type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="city">
</form>

 <button class="button getbids" >GET BIDS</button> 


 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', '.getbids', function() {
  var loggedIn = {{ auth()->check() ? 'true' : 'false' }};
   if (loggedIn)
  window.location.replace('customer/dashboard');
  if(!loggedIn)
  $('#loginModal').modal('show'); 
   });
   </script>
```

**Route**

```
  Route::group(['middleware'=>['rolecustomer']], function () {

  Route::get('/customer/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('customer.dashboard');
 });
```

**controller:**

```
  public function index()
   {
   return view('index.customer.customerdashboard');
     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel use session to store input field and pass to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042744/laravel-use-session-to-store-input-field-and-pass-to-another-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put something something permanently for entire session, you can use `$session->put('key', 'value')`.

In your case,

```
public function bids(Request $request){

    $request->session()->put('country', $request->country);
    $request->session()->put('state', $request->state);
    $request->session()->put('city', $request->city);
    return redirect()->route('route_name');

}
```

Then in next page, just, use `Session::get($key)`.

```
<div>
   <p>Country : {{ Session::get('country') }}</p>
   <p>State: {{ Session::get('state') }}</p>
   <p>City: {{ Session::get('city') }}</p>
</div>
```

Or, a more convenient way to access a Session is first check if the value is in the Session or not by `Session::has('key_name')`.

```
<div>
   <p>Country : {{ (Session::has('country') ? Session::get('country') : '' ) }}</p>
   .....
</div>
```

Comment: didn't work! its complicated what I have to do in web.php? route is problem with me and do I have to modify the form like action and methods?

Answer (score 1):

To store the value in the session, pass the value of the input to laravel's session like this.

`Session::set('input_field', 'field_value');`

And to retrieve the session use the following piece of code.

`Session::get('input_field');`

More informations on laravel session [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session).

Comment: I have the input : <input class="indexinput" type="text" id="country" name="country" 
 placeholder="Country">
so where I have to put `Session::set('input_field', 'filed_value');
and what do you mean by input_field? is it country? as id=country? can you clear where I have to put every line you have wrote??

Comment: So basically the laravel sets session values like `key-value`. In the above example, `input_field` is the `key` name I used. It can be anything, it can be your name, the input name, whatever you wish to like to call the key. And the second parameter `filed_value` is the value you need to pass. In your case, pass the `input value` or the value you would like to pass. As soon as you submit, the session will be created with the key name. When the next page loads, retrieve the session value by using the key name you set. As here in the example, its `input_field`